# Unable to read path because of no path extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, path, youtube

So, i am using [TCBlobDownload](https://github.com/thibaultCha/TCBlobDownload) to download large files with a URL.

The url's that i use have no extension. For example this url [Youtube link](http://r13---sn-5hn7sner.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?itag=36&sparams=algorithm,burst,cp,factor,id,ip,ipbits,itag,source,upn,expire&ip=87.208.37.229&key=yt1&cp=U0hWTlFNTl9NT0NONl9JR1JCOlVZNU1FTU9sWGIz&upn=mID5mzBcOXg&fexp=937500,941209,939702,930625,936204,939104,924606,929117,929121,929906,929907,929922,929923,929127,929129,929131,929930,936403,925726,936310,925720,925722,925718,925714,929917,906945,929933,920302,906842,913428,920605,919811,935020,935021,913563,919373,930803,908536,938701,931924,934005,936308,909549,901608,900816,912711,934507,907231,936312,906001&source=youtube&expire=1379120185&ipbits=8&burst=40&algorithm=throttle-factor&mv=m&mt=1379095564&factor=1.25&ms=au&id=b8f523cfeae4042f&sver=3&signature=9BA7466AF68C385D32E361FB79A12EBADE73D35F.5B54FDB8F24E310F2891097135EDC39EE38BC58D) When it finishes download from the URL it saves it in the tmp path directory "/Users/NAME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/ID/tmp/videoplayback", the size and stuff is all good. if i add the .mp4 extension my self within the finder i am able to play this video.

But as you can see the path has no extension like .mp4 .. And when i browse to this file it shows that the "kind" of it is Document when it needs to be a .mp4 extension..

So i am unable to read from this path. If i use this 
`NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile];` it return a null

So my question is.. How can i add a extension to a existing file in the tmp path?

Thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you asked for

```
NSString *tmp = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp"];
NSString *filename  = @"my video";
NSString *extension = @"mp4";
NSString *path = [[tmp stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] stringByAppendingPathExtension:extension];

NSLog(@"Path: %@",path);
```

so, by doing just:

```
pathToFile = [pathToFile stringByAppendingPathExtension:extension];
```

should work

Comment: This doens't change/add the extension of a file path thought... Because you don't say that the file should change. Right?

Comment: It is just constructing the path to a file, it doesn't rename the file

Comment: But thats the question. How can i change the name of a file which has no extension?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4", pathToFile]];
```